# Printing multiple variables on seperate lines Python 2

Tags: python-2.7

Hi there I am trying to create variables and then print each variable on a seperate line without printing each variable seperately like this:

```
string_name = "Pierre"
integer_age = 36
float_height_in_metres = 1.94
print string_name 
print integer_age
print float_height_in_metres
```

I would like to only use the print command once. I tried this, but an error occurs when trying to run.

```
string_name = "Pierre"
integer_age = 36
float_height_in_metres = 1.94
print string_name + \ninteger_age + n\float_height_in_metres
```

Is it possible to only use the print command once?

Comment: What error occurs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because `+` concatenates strings only, but you pass a string, an integer and a float. The error you should get is pretty clear about this:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

You have to convert each to their string representation first:

```
print string_name + '\n' + str(integer_age) + '\n' + str(float_height_in_metres)
```

Comment: Thank you I am still learning, so what you are saying is that I have to cast each integer and float into a string before I can print them using +